# Композиция в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

У меня есть класс `Class_А` с некоторыми полями и методами. 
И есть класс `UIViewController` `(h. m)` c методом `Method_X1`. 
Мне нужно создать в самом классе `UIViewController` экземпляр класса `Class_А` (ну как композиция делается) и обращаться к этому объекта из метода `Method_X1`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Поясните, с чем именно у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: `Class_A *a = [[Class_A alloc] init]; `
Если я его вставлю во ViewDidLoad - не будет работать код 
`[self a]` - вызванный из метода   `Method_X1`. даст ошибку "No visible interface for ViewController declares the selector "a".

Comment: В секции ViewController.h создавать перед секцией @interface
Class_A *a = [[Class_A alloc] init]; даёт ошибки
 "Use of undeclared identifier "Class_A";
"Unknown type name Class_A *a."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Композиция**, в отличии от агрегации, в первую очередь управляет временем жизни объекта. В вашем примере `UIViewController` должен создавать внутри себя `Class_A` и управлять им:

```
#import "UIViewController.h"
#import "Class_A.h"

@implementation UIViewController {
    Class_A * _classA;
}

- (instancetype) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classA = [[Class_A alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) Method_X1 {
    [_classA method];
}

@end
```

**Агрегация** же не управляет временем жизни объекта, а только получает экземпляр извне (через конструктор, свойство или метод):

UIViewController.h

```
@class Class_A;

@interface UIViewController : NSObject

- (instancetype) initWithClassA: (Class_A *) classA;
- (void) Method_X1;

@end
```

UIViewController.m

```
#import "UIViewController.h"
#import "Class_A.h"

@implementation UIViewController {
    Class_A * _classA;
}

- (instancetype) initWithClassA: (Class_A *) classA {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _classA = classA;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) Method_X1 {
    [_classA method];
}

@end
```